# Audio sniffing in python?

Tags: c++, python, audio

I was wondering if there was a way to "sniff" the music that is going out to the local computers' speakers.  I was hoping to do this in python because I want to port it over to the raspberry pi, although it isn't strictly required.

The idea is basically have something you run that is totally separate from your music player.  So it wouldn't launch the music file, just look at the stream going from the other program to the computers speakers and act on it.

P.S. python please :)

Comment: why did you tag it with "C++" if you want Python?

Comment: b/c it doesn't have to be python. Just preferred.  I want to hear any solutions that could be in C++ as well.

Comment: Any answer to this question is going to be very platform specific - what target system do you intend to run the code on?  Just the raspberry pi?

Comment: Yea pretty much.  I'm prototyping on my linux machine before I port it over b/c the rpi is kind of a hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyAudio is a good tool for audio manipulation in Python. This person: [record output sound in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046663/record-output-sound-in-python) was able to record sound output from their computer with PyAudio without access to the original file.

Comment: That looks like a very promising lead!  He is even recording samples at a rate just like you would need for fourier transforms!  I didn't realize PyAudio could do that.