# Python Intercepting/reading audio output level in python/linux

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to write something that catches the audio being played to the speakers/headphones/soundcard and see whether it is playing and what the longest silence is. This is to test an application that is being executed and to see if it stops playing audio after a certain point, as such i don't actually need to really know what the audio itself is, just whether or not there is audio playing.

I need this to be fully programmatic (so not requiring the use of GUI tools or the like, to set up an environment). I know applications like projectM do this, I just can't for the life of me find anything anywhere that denotes how.

An audio level meter would also work for this, as would ossiliscope data or the like, really would take any recommendation.

Comment: we should do more useful edits!

Comment: I don't understand what that statement means.

Comment: update on this, I ended up just using the pulseaudio bindings to fix this problem. via link: http://freshfoo.com/blog/pulseaudio_monitoring

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very similar question: [record output sound in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046663/record-output-sound-in-python)

You could try to route your output to a new device with [jack](http://jackaudio.org/) and record this with [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/). There are Python Bindings for portaudio called [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) and for jack called [PyJack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py-jack/). I have never used the latter one but pyaudio works great.

---

Comment: I saw that post already, as well as an example using PulseAudio(which was much more bare bones). The jack solution is a bit too much, as it has to install a server on the system and I don't want everyone to have to deal with that. The pulseaudio one is a little better, but still requires a library.I am hopefully looking for a python-only solution, maybe one that uses the OSS or something more core to python?