# Write Mac synthesized speech output to a file

Tags: python, macos, text-to-speech

I have the following Python code, which outputs the spoken text "This is a test". Can someone tell me how I redirect this output to an audio file?

```
from  AppKit import NSSpeechSynthesizer
import time

nssp = NSSpeechSynthesizer
ve = nssp.alloc().init()
from_voice = "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex"

data = u'''
This is a test.
'''

def say_data (data):
        ve.setVoice_(from_voice)
        ve.startSpeakingString_(data)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ve.isSpeaking():
             time.sleep(1)

say_data (data)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046663/record-output-sound-in-python

Comment: you want to use `startSpeakingString_toURL_`

Comment: Ok, that worked! I had to add a line: `result_url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_("./foo.aiff")`  and then a line `ve.startSpeakingString_toURL_(data, result_url)`

Comment: And at the top of my script `from Cocoa import NSURL`