# ffmpeg not finding system/speaker audio device

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to screen record with audio, and the video portion is fine but I can't record audio because ffmpeg can only find my microphone, but not my speaker/system audio.

```
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x135f046a0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x135f046a0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x135f046a0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x135f046a0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x135f046a0] [0] MacBook Pro Microphone
```

Python Code

```
os.system(f"""ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_device_index 1 -i "default:none" -t 00:00:05 -y -r 10 recording{x}.mov""")
```

Is there a reason why it's not picking up the system audio? I tried looking around and struggling to find an answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your input url `-i "default:none"` is disabling the audio. I think you need `-i "1:0"` based on the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation) (See the examples)

Comment: hey thank you, I actually tried that first, but 0 refers to the microphone and I want to capture from the speaker instead. For instance if I'm running a game or a video from YT, I want to capture the audio too.

Comment: Oh, I see (I was wondering why you are mentioning speaker). You have one fundamental issue: speaker is not an input device. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046663) though. It's an old one but if you can find an app/device which feed through lineout to mic and it can be detected by AVFoundation, you might be able to pull it off.  good luck

Answer (score 0):

It's a three-step process, absolutely doable.

First, you change the audio output in your application (e.g video player) to an audio device like [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole).

Second, you find the <audio_index> of this new audio device, just an integer, by:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
```

The output looks similar to this:
[image]

Example:

If I want to stream to Blackhole, the corresponding avfoundation would option would be `-i "none:1"`

Third, you must specify the index number which is assigned by the MacOS system for your audio.

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_device_index 1 -i "none:<audio_index>" -t 00:00:05 -y -r 10 recording{x}.mov
```